# Zoom on custom theme without child

Tags: theme-development, customization, woocommerce-offtopic

I'm currently developing my own theme in WooCommerce, it's a great way to get familiar with it, and a rather fantastic plugin...

I worked on a lot of aspects, including carts, but now, I'm attacking the product page and I wanted to activate the zoom capability that comes with WooCommerce.

So I added this in my function.php page, as to test everything (sinope's being my theme's name):

```
function sinope_setup() {
    add_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-zoom' );
    add_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-lightbox' );
    add_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-slider' );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'sinope_setup' );
```

Now, I can tell it adds empty html code at the end of my theme:

[image: Empty Code]

But worse, the images do show, but only as href links, no zoom effect whatsoever:

[image: Zoom not working]

What am I missing?

If I activate the TwentySeventeen theme, of course, all is fine and zoom is OK.

Comment: are you getting js errors?

Comment: None :(  It's good news, my code is tight.  But no errors.

Comment: what happens if you just put those lines directly into functions.php?

Comment: What lines, these?

    function sinope_setup() {
        add_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-zoom' );
        add_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-lightbox' );
        add_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-slider' );
    }
    add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'sinope_setup' );

Nothing at all. It just generates those empty HTML tags that are, clearly, the content of the gallery but without the actual images.

Comment: what about image sizes? do you have to specify different sizes for it to work?

Comment: Those images are showing up as clickable links (the first one being the featured image of the product and the two other ones, the gallery).  I adjusted the size with CSS, but if I inspect the individual images, all the data-attributes (ie data-caption, data-src, srcset, etc...) all show up.